# TensorCamera on React-Native does not work

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

So I'm trying to make an app that get's a model from Google Teachable Machine and detect it with tensor camera but tensor camera doesn't work. Everytime when i start the app i get black screen and these warnings:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: gl.createVertexArray is not a function. (In 'gl.createVertexArray()', 'gl.createVertexArray' is undefined)]

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this3.camera.props')]

Below is my App.js code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import { cameraWithTensors } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { getModel, startPrediction } from './helpers/tensor-helper';





export default function App() {
  const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);
  const cameraRef = useRef();
  const [isTfReady, setIsTfReady] = useState(false);
  const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = useState(false);
  const [model, setModel] = useState();






  function handleCameraStream(images, updatePreview, gl) {

    const loop = async () => {

      const nextImageTensor = images.next.value();
      if (!model || !nextImageTensor) throw new Error('No model or image tensor');
      const output = startPrediction();
      console.log(output);



      updatePreview();
      gl.endFrameEXP();
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    loop();
  }


  useEffect(() => {

    const yukle = async () => {
      console.log('girdi');
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      await tf.ready();
      setModel(await getModel())


    }

    yukle();
  }, [])

  let textureDims;
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    textureDims = {
      height: 1920,
      width: 1080,
    };
  } else {
    textureDims = {
      height: 1200,
      width: 1600,
    };
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <TensorCamera
        // Standard Camera props
        style={styles.camera}
        type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
        // Tensor related props
        cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
        cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
        resizeHeight={200}
        resizeWidth={152}
        resizeDepth={3}
        onReady={(images, updatePreview, gl) => handleCameraStream(images, updatePreview, gl)}
        autorender={true}
      />
    </View>
  );



}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  camera: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
});
```

And these are the helper functions:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
import { bundleResourceIO, decodeJpeg } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';

const BITMAP_DIMENSION = 224;

const modelJson = require('../model/model.json');
const modelWeights = require('../model/weights.bin');

// 0: channel from JPEG-encoded image
// 1: gray scale
// 3: RGB image
const TENSORFLOW_CHANNEL = 3;

export const getModel = async () => {
    try {
        // wait until tensorflow is ready
        await tf.ready();
        // load the trained model
        return await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Could not load model', error);
    }
};



export const startPrediction = async (model, tensor) => {
    try {
        // predict against the model
        const output = await model.predict(tensor);
        // return typed array
        return output.dataSync();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error predicting from tesor image', error);
    }
};
```

I would be glad if anyone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your onReady function to this:

```
onReady={handleCameraStream}
```